# Increment date variable variable 33

Tags: vba, excel

i want to do this :

```
dim inc as long , J as date 

inc = 8
j = 2 h / inc '2:00 / 8 

msgbox j      'j = 00:15 

range("A1").value = j ' = 00: 15
```

can you help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
Public Sub tmpTest()

Dim inc As Long, J As Date

inc = 8
J = "02:00:00"
'or use the following line
'J = TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)

MsgBox CDate(CDbl(J) / 8)      'j = 00:15

Range("A1").Value = CDate(CDbl(J) / 8) ' = 00: 15

End Sub
```